# Mass Email Alert to Salesforce Users

Tags: email, workflow, scheduled-apex

We have a requirement to alert the opportunity owner 90 days after the opportunity was created and meeting certain data criteria.

We need to issue this alert on a daily basis for all matching opportunities on that day.

I am thinking of creating a Scheduled Batch Apex that will pick up all matching opportunities every day and update a hidden field if the opportunity matches the data criteria and if it is 90 days since the opportunity was created.

I will be creating a WF Email Alert that will send out the email to the Opportunity Owners when the hidden field is updated.

Are there any other ways to achieve this ?

Comment: Time-dependent action on Workflows or Scheduled actions on Process - either one can do this

Comment: I'm pretty sure with time based actions it reevaluates the criteria. No need for a hidden field.

Answer (score 1):

If you have your security set up properly ,you can try scheduling a Report .Create a report that meets your need with proper filters and assuming you have great security in place ,you can select My opportunities as filter .Your other users will have to Subscribe for the report.

[image]

[image]